# Get the name of the sound devices in C#

Tags: c#, audio, driver

I need to get the names of a computer sound drivers. Put it in a list or string.
All that I found was a "int" return methods of the "winmm.dll", like "waveInGetDevCapsA"     and "waveInGetDevCapsW".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to enumerate audio devices, it becomes very easy by using [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/). It requires DirectX to be installed in the computer though.

For example, to enumerate the audio capture devices:

```
 DeviceCollection coll = DirectSoundCapture.GetDevices();
 foreach( DeviceInformation dev in coll ) {
    ...

 }
```

To enumerate audio playback devices:

```
DeviceCollection coll = DirectSound.GetDevices();
   foreach( DeviceInformation di in coll ) {

   }
```

The `DeviceInformation` class has a `Description` property of type `string`. It also has a `DriverGuid` property of type `Guid` that enables you to "select" the device to perform either audio capture or playback (that can also be done by means of SlimDX).

**EDIT: a method using Winmm.dll** 
Please take a look at the following [entry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18685/Enumerating-Sound-Recording-Devices-Using-winmm-dl) in Code Project. It builds an enumerator using Winmm.dll only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's works. Thanks a lot, but I need something that using a native winmm.dll method, or another native way.